# trouble using IN statement with mysql and php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm attempting to pull several users from a database based on what's stored in a specific column using an IN statement.

The users are stored in a column separated by "~" which is why I use str_replace to remove it so it's just numbers. I tried it using a comma instead and that didn't work either. For example, users 1,2 and 3 would be stored in the column as "1~2~3". $stripSymbol is working and properly displays the users, so I'm confused as to why I can't get the sql statement to work.

```
if($eventBy == $_SESSION['userid']){ 
            if(($requested !=="") OR ($requested !=="~")){
                $stripSymbol = str_replace("~","",$requested); //$requested is the list of users
                echo $stripSymbol; //used for testing, displays the values properly so I know this works
            $userInvites = mysql_query("select userid,username from users where userid IN ($stripSymbol)");
            $userArray = mysql_fetch_array($userInvites);
            $userN = $userArray['username'];
            echo $userN; //testing to see if it's pulling the values properly, nothing is displayed
            }
        }
```

Here's my updated code. It's only displaying the last value in the column.

```
if($eventBy == $_SESSION['userid']){ 
            if(($requested !=="") OR ($requested !=="~")){
                $stripSymbol = explode("~",$requested); 
                $stripSymbol = "'" . implode("', '", $stripSymbol) . "'";
                $userInvites = mysql_query("select userid,username from users where userid IN (".$stripSymbol.")");
                $userArray = mysql_fetch_array($userInvites);
                $userN = $userArray['username'];
                echo $userN; //testing to see if it's pulling the values properly, nothing is displayed
            }
        }
```

Comment: Let's do this `print_r($requested)` and then before the query `print_r($stripSymbol)` and then after the `mysql_query` `if(!$userInvites) { echo mysql_error(); }`

Comment: print_r($requested) outputs 3~2~ and print_r($stripSymbol) outputs '3', '2', "

Comment: Lets remove the ~ in the end. You could add `$requested = trim($requested, '~')` before you call `explode`

Comment: You should still add `if(!$userInvites) { echo $q . mysql_error(); }` just before mysql_fetch_array to see the error from MySQL http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

Answer (score 0):

You should change the replace function:

```
 $stripSymbol = str_replace("~",",",$requested);
```

Now it replaces "~" with ",".

Add some debugging information:

```
 $userInvites = mysql_query("select userid,username from users where userid IN ($stripSymbol)") or die($q . " " . mysql_error());
 $userArray = mysql_fetch_array($userInvites);
```

Comment: I tried that and get the following error Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in...

Comment: Add the debugging code and we will see what exactly is the mysql error.

Comment: mysql_fetch_array returns that warning because the prev function mysql_query() failes and returns false. So, i edited my answer and added mysql_query() or die($q . mysql_error()) to see the error thrown by MySQL, not by PHP.

Answer (score 0):

This is your code corrected:

```
if(($requested !=="") OR ($requested !=="~")){
                $stripSymbol = explode("~", $requested); //$requested is the list of users
                $stripSymbol = "'" . implode("', '", $requested) . "'";
                echo $stripSymbol; //used for testing, displays the values properly so I know this works
            $userInvites = mysql_query("select userid,username from users where userid IN ($stripSymbol)");
            $userArray = mysql_fetch_array($userInvites);
            foreach($userArray as $item)
                {
                  $userN = $item['username'];
                  echo $userN . "<br/>"; //testing to see if it's pulling the values properly, nothing is displayed
                }
            }
```

Comment: Sorry, guess I didn't explain it clearly enough. There are multiple users stored in  $stripSymbol that I want to look up so I'm trying to have multiple rows returned.

Comment: Ok look, insetad of this command: $stripSymbol = str_replace("~","",$requested);

try: $stripSymbol = explode("~",$requested);
$stripSymbol = "'" . implode("', '", $stripSymbol) . "'";

and it'll work.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it's only displaying the last value in the column.

Comment: Forgot to say when I echo $stripSymbol it shows two values but when I echo the sql statement only 1 value is shown. Also, I updated my code in the original post so you can see what I currently have.

Comment: I updated the post to answer your last question. check it out now.

Comment: Now it's displaying the first letter of the username and the userid number, twice. Getting closer!

Comment: it should be working correctly now. check the database if the usernames in users table match the results displayed. comment:echo $stripSymbol; so that you get just the database usernames result.